# How to mock dependencies for testing in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocking

I want to write some unit-tests for my applicatin, can I somehow "mock" some dependencies used with require('dependencyname')?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[You are looking for Proxyquire :)](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire)

```
//file1
var get    = require('simple-get');
var assert = require('assert');

module.exports = function fetch (callback) {
  get('https://api/users', callback);
};

//test file
var proxyquire = require('proxyquire');
var fakeResponse = {status:200};
var fetch = proxyquire('./get', {
  'simple-get': function (url, callback) {
    process.nextTick(function () {
      callback(null, fakeResponse)
    })
  }
});

fetch(function (err, res) {
  assert(res.statusCode, 200)
});
```

Straight out of their docs.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Fixed my answer.

Answer (score 1):

yes, for example with jest => https://facebook.github.io/jest/

```
// require model to be mocked
const Mail = require('models/mail');

describe('test ', () => {

    // mock send function
    Mail.send = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve());

    // clear mock after each test
    afterEach(() => Mail.send.mockClear());

    // unmock function
    afterAll(() => jest.unmock(Mail.send));

    it('', () =>
        somefunction().then(() => {
            // catch params passed to Mail.send triggered by somefunction()
            const param = Mail.send.mock.calls[0][0];
        })
    );
});
```

Comment: Don't you think that suggesting a framework is a bit much on such a small use case? :)